# Why does setting a class attribute after declaration return an error in python?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm working on a dungeon styled game, and I made a file called places.py to store the places. I am using a class, then adding attributes to the class. I received an error, and here is the error message:

> E0001:invalid syntax (, line 8)

Here would be my code for places.py:

```
class place(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name=''
        self.nearplaces=[]
        self.ground=[]
        self.monsters=[]
1 = place
1.name='Ruby City'
1.nearplaces=[2,3]
1.ground=[1]
1.monsters=[]
```

It is confusing how, after declaration, I receive an error when trying to change the attributes. This may be a very simple question, but I wish to know why it does not work, and how to make it work. Thank you.

Comment: Variable names cannot begin with an integer. Apart from that you are not creating an instance, you assign the class.

Comment: They cannot? Why can't they? Can you please give me a link?

Comment: They just... can't (@Phydeaux's answer below links the documentation stating that they can't.). This is intuitive if you consider how a parser actually works - consider the example print(3e2). Is that trying to print the number 30.0 or the variable `3e2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you cannot use integer literals, like `1`, as variable names. This is to avoid ambiguity, so the interpreter knows whether it is looking at a variable or a number (see [rules for Python identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)).

Secondly, to properly instantiate your class you need to use `()`.

Try:

```
level_1 = place()
level_1.name='Ruby City'
level_1.nearplaces=[2,3]
level_1.ground=[1]
level_1.monsters=[]
```